# How to jump where exception caught in IntelliJ debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, exception

I have

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

line in my code. Unfortunately, this exception has no any effect: i.e. no message appeared and no program crash.

This is because code is called from somewhere in system library and there exception is caught and processed.

How to find this place?

If I press `F8` on this line, I jump to the code inside `Scene`:

```
            try {
                tm = dndGesture.processTargetDrop(dragEvent);
            } finally {
                DragboardHelper.setDataAccessRestriction(
                        dndGesture.dragboard, true);
            }
```

but does this code catches an exception? I think it should just execute `finally` block and then go to somewhere's `catch` block. But this doesn't happen: if I continue pressing `F8` I see no any `try/catch/finally` blocks.

How can this happen?

Comment: The code shown does not catch any exceptions, so it is correct the finally block is executed and your exception will be flung out somewhere else. If there are no other catch blocks the application or thread will fail with your exception as thrown.

Comment: sorry for asking, but maybe you found a solution and just forgot to post it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an Exception Breakpoint, which you can set to break on exception even though it is caught. In the Breakpoints dialog (it by default is bound to Ctrl+Shift+F8 or Cmd+Shift+F8 depending on platform, or click [image: the breakpoint dialog button] in the Debug task pane), create a Java Exception Breakpoint with notifications on both Caught and Uncaught.

[image: Screenshot of Breakpoint dialog]

Then, once your breakpoint triggers, you should be able to step through the code and see the call stack and see what's catching it.

For more information, see [Creating Exception Breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-exception-breakpoints.html) in the IntelliJ IDEA documentation, which links to specifics about all the configuration options in the breakpoint dialog.

Comment: I think this is different. Since I know where exception is thrown (explicitly in my code) I need not find this place. I need to find what happen with exception next.

Comment: I use a system with many libraries and calls. I tried to do it your way, but it's extremely hard to spot (some reflection, libraries for which I don't have code near me etc).